# Why Isn't Session Null

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am using the following code to delivery the user to a Welcome page if they are already logged in, or back to the login page if they are not.

```
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if(session == null){
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else{
        //User already logged in. Send to home.
        response.sendRedirect("Welcome");
    }
```

First time around, it works fine, but if I reload the page even once it sends the user to the welcome page and inevitably sends me back a 500 error because there are elements on that page that cannot be loaded because the user log in code has not been executed.

Does a session get started automatically even if request.getSession(true) is not declared when a page is reloaded? Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `request.getSession(false)` returns null *if* there is no current session. I suggest to compare a key too.

Please take a look at this threads.

1. [Do JSPs always create a session?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/294149/JSP/java/Do-JSPs-always-create-session)
2. [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)

Comment: I agree with this. Don't rely on nullness of the season to see if the user is logged in or not. When he logs in, set an attribute (e.g. `session.setAttribute("userId", user.getId())` and use that to see if the user is logged in or not. Otherwise if you want to use the built-in security mechanisms provided by JEE, @PaoloVictor's solution makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the session is being created upon forwarding to `login.jsp`. That's necessary because the user has to be assigned to an unauthenticated request and *then* authenticate it. If you want to redirect based on whether the user is logged in or not, use `SessionContext`'s `getCallerPrincipal`.

For more info, check [this (somewhat old, but still relevant) article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170809&seqNum=10)